# Bootstrap modal not working on my vue app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am developing an application with laravel and vuejs.

I have require bootstrap in my application.

I tried to call the bootstrap modal but it is not working

user.vue

```
<div class="card-tools">
    <div class="btn btn-success">
        <router-link to="create-user" class="btn btn-success">Add New
            <i class="fas fa-user-plus"></i>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                Launch demo modal
            </button>


           <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog">
                   <div class="modal-content">
                       <div class="modal-header">
                           <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
                           </button>
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-body">
                           ...
                       </div>
                       <div class="modal-footer">
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                       </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

resources/js/bootstrap.js

```
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

    require('bootstrap');
    require('admin-lte');
    
} catch (e) {}
```

Comment: How are you importing bootstrap into your app?  Please provide the html or package.json that imports bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

for your application in vue you need to use bootstrap-vue.

https://bootstrap-vue.org/

Here you can find different examples of how to implement bootstrap-vue in your project.